# Use and difference of "Routing and Analysis metric" and "Radial metric" in SDNA Integral Network

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, sdna

I want to know what it means to select Euclidean Metrics and Angular Metrics in SDNA Integral Network between "Routing and Analysis Metrics" and "Radial Metrics ".

Answer (score 0):

Radial metrics define the locality of analysis around each link. It's like a spatial buffer, we only compute stats for each link based on what's in its local buffer. By default we choose (network) Euclidean for the radial metric as it's easiest to explain to others e.g. "all surrounding network closer than 2km as measured along the network".

Once you've defined that radius, the routing metric defines how you'd like to travel through it, and the analysis metric defines what you'd like to report about your journeys. At present these are one and the same. So for example for mean distance, from each origin, we compute shortest paths (according to the routing metric) to everywhere in the radius, then measure the distance along each (according to the analysis metric which currently cannot be set separatlely to the routing one - e.g. if it's angular, this measurement will be in degrees, not metres), then report the mean. For betweenness there isn't really an analysis metric but we consider flows based on the routing metric.

Note that in a transport model, radial metric roughly speaking defines demand (or unimodal mode choice) - whether or not a trip will take place - while routing metric defines route choice - the route it takes. For a fully rational *homo economicus* these would probably be the same thing, and indeed in sDNA+ you can set them to the same thing, which is my personal preference. On the other hand, we're not fully rational beings, and also sometimes in transport models we'd prefer to make something easily explainable rather than try to model behaviour too closely. That said, in transport it's usually important to get demand modelling right, so I'd lean towards a more sophisticated choice of radial metric.

Comment: If I select Euclidean under "Routing and Analysis Metrics", what is the unit of my "Radii" option? Degrees or meters?

Comment: Whatever the spatial unit is in the projection of your input data (I recommend projecting to a CRS that uses metres!)